# How to design a finite state machine to detect 0110 in the input?

Tags: finite-automata, strings, substrings, digital-circuits

My task is to design a FSM whose output goes high for a single cycle whenever the pattern 0110 is detected on its input. The patterns may overlap, so an input 0110110 of would cause the output to go high twice- once for the first pattern (0110110), and once for the second pattern (0110110). a is used for the input and f is used for the output.

I am assuming I will need five state bubbles [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghKNq.png)

Is this correct or am I missing some cases based on the pattern going high twice if the pattern overlaps?

Comment: The idea of output going "high" or "low" is probably not particularly familiar to Computer Scientists. I suspect most people here learned finite automata in terms of acceptor machines, reading in a string then either accepting or rejecting it. Are you using this for circuit/electrical design?

Comment: Possible dup: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11780/755

Comment: @jmite: I know Computer Science is not about computers, but let's be honest: we know *that* much. At least I do :)

Comment: It depends highly on the type of CS education, particularly whether a school does it as part of science or engineering. I'm not saying it's off topic, I'm just asking for some background.

Comment: This is certainly not a duplicate of a question about nondeterministic finite automata: the asker seems to be looking for a circuit design and real electronic circuits are not nondeterministic. I also don't think the question is unclear so I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: Low and high can be taken as symbols of an output alphabet. The device asked for is actually a finite state transucer (aka GSM) which is a beast known to CS. This seems to be just an instance of the substring matching, solved by Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm (among others), and to be found in hardware at the entrance door of many appartment buildings (at least in my country).

Comment: The diagram should be included on site in the question. The OP should use more standard automata theory notations in his diagram.

Comment: The expression "to go high twice" makes me wonder whether the question is to find  a sequential automaton whose output is the number of (possibly overlapping) patterns $0110$ in the input word.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're missing the overlap case, if I understand your diagram correctly.  This does the trick:

```
A    // goto B if read 0 else stay
B    // goto C if read 1 else stay
C    // goto D if read 1 else goto B
D    // goto E if read 0 else goto A
E    // emit rising edge, goto B
```

assuming that you have a falling edge after every read.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is just an instance of the [substring searching problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm), for the
specific substring $0110$. There are
several algorithms that solve it.

Given that the search is to be done in real-time, I guess the best
algorithm is the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). For any string to be
searched, the KMP algorithm will compute the table for a DFA that
recognizes all occurences of that string in any string given as input.

Note however that the finite state device to be constructed is not really a DFA, but a deterministic [finite
state transducer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer) (also known as Generalized sequential machines - GSM), as it has an output for each transition, which is
either *low* or *high*. The words *low* and *high* may be taken as symbol of
an output alphabet, even if they have physical meaning in the context
of the question.

I leave it as an exercise to apply the KMP algorithm to the specific
example of the question, since the question is actually asking how to design the finite state transducer, and is not asking to actually do it.